# IntelliJ IDEA автоматически переводит поля в БД на китайский при клике на них

Tags: intellij-idea

Когда я открываю просмотр БД в IntelliJ IDEA и кликаю на любое поле, оно автоматически переводится на китайский язык. Кто-нибудь знает как это можно исправить ?
[image: Скриншот из IDE]

Версия идеи: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 Ultimate

Comment: Кодировку в правом нижнем углу пробовали менять?

Comment: При просмотре БД там не указывается кодировка вообще

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка разрешилась сама собой, не знаю как, я просто перезагрузил пк)